# Question about Selenium: find element by its child link text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

The front end I'm working on look like this and there will be a lot of similar ones with different dates. On website it's shown as a form.

```
<tr>
    <td height="15"><a href="link"><font size="3">file.zip</font></a></td>
    <td height="15"><font size="3">10-29-2018</font></td>
</tr>
```

On high level, I want to download all files for a specific day like "10-29-2018".

On implementation, I'm trying to first get all the parent web elements  whose child element  has text like "10-29-2018". And through those parent elements  I can get the "link" for download.

I got stuck on finding element by its child's link text. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This one should work:

```
//tr[td="10-29-2018"]//a
```

...if you want to locate link by *following cell with date*. Note that `"10-29-2018"` is not *link text*. Link text in this case is `"file.zip"`

Comment: @Carl, yes, `By.xpath`

Comment: This isn't working... I think you meant something more like `//tr[.//font[.='10-29-2018']]//a`? I tested it and it's working

Comment: @JeffC , Yep, it's not working **now** after you've updated HTML source sample :)

Comment: Having said that... you probably shouldn't create a locator that is so fragile to HTML whitespace formatting changes... mine works in both cases... ;)

Comment: What does `td="10-29-2018"` do? I don't think I've seen that before. Is it just a shorthand for `td[.="10-29-2018"]`?

Comment: @JeffC , `//tr[.//font[.='10-29-2018']]//a` is also good :) Yes. Note that dot stands for *context node* which is `td` in this case. So `[td[.="10-29-2018"]]` means the same as `[td="10-29-2018"]`

Answer (score 2):

Within a `<tr>` among several `<td>` you need to locate the `<td>` containing the date e.g **10-29-2018** and with respect to this `<td>` you need to locate the preceding `<td>` which have a `<a>` tag as a *descendant* which you can *click() to initiate download* and you can use *xpath* as:

```
//tr//td[contains(.,'10-29-2018')]//preceding::td[1]/a
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me where you learned to write this. Is there any tutorial?

Comment: @Carl this [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) is the best starting point. Moving forward contributing on StackOverflow will help you to get precise and perfect.